# XSL-FO 組版と CSS 組版の違い

Tags: css, xsl-fo, 組版

最近スタック・オーバーフローに [xsl-fo](/questions/tagged/xsl-fo) 関連のご質問が投稿されており、XSL Formatting Objects について知りました。

しかし Wikipedia にある説明を読むに、XSL-FO 組版のやり方は CSS 組版のやり方と殆ど同じなのではないか、と思えてきました。そして、両者の違いについて興味が湧きました。たとえば Wikipedia の ["XSL Formatting Objects"](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects) には以下のように書かれています。

> XSL-FOとCSSは、良く似ている概念を採用しているが、いくつかの違いもある。 ブロックとインライン要素の概念は、CSSと非常に良く似ている。 間隔 (padding) と余白 (margin) の規則のいくつかは、CSSと異なる。 表記方向 (direction) に関しては、XSL-FO ではページの特性に沿って全て指定することができる。 *(2018年4月23日閲覧)*

XSL-FO と CSS のどちらを採用するか判断するための材料として、こういった違いは重要そうです。そこで、質問です。

組版をするにあたり、XSL-FO と CSS の "表現力" は同等ですか？　つまり、一方では〇〇という組み方ができるものの、他方ではそれを行う方法が無い、あるいは難しいといったことはありますか？　必要であれば、両者の規格のバージョンを適当に設定して頂いて構いません。

Comment: XMLTと組み合わせて出来るドキュメント構造編集能力、テキスト置換などの編集、ソートなどはCSSよりXSL-FOの方が上かと…表現力(デザイン的な？)の意味がよくつかめていません。

Comment: @Myaku さん、コメントありがとうございます。具体的にどのような違いがあるか予想しにくかったため、"表現力" という言葉を厳密に定義することなく使いました。デザインや計算能力、実装手法なども含めて、一方のみでやりやすいことはあるか、ということが知りたいです。既にご指摘頂いたものもその範疇だと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参照されている、Wikipedia にありますように、その生い立ちが

「XSL-FOは、複数のページで構成される媒体を想定して設計された。一方HTMLとCSSは、ページの概念が無い媒体 （コンピュータ画面など） を想定して設計されている。」

という違いがあります．

CSSもwikipedia にありますように、

「表示媒体（モニターや TV、紙媒体など）によって自動的にスタイルシートを変更できるようにし、それに附随して音声ブラウザへの対応、印刷媒体への対応が行われ、フォントなどの表示機能の拡張や、ボックスの概念の修正などが行われた。」

と、印刷媒体への対応も進められていますが、その仕様は、まだドラフトやそれ以前の状態であったりします．

このような状況ですので、組版の対象媒体が何なのか、によってその仕様も含めて向き不向きがあるように思います．

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。確かにページが表現できるかは重要です。一方で、[CSS Multi-column Layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-multicol-1/) などの仕様がドラフト段階なのはそうなのですが、通常 Vivliostyle.js などを使って CSS 組版をする場合、これらを前提とした上でやるものだと思っていたのですが、如何でしょうか？　HTML+CSS を使った組版も現在ではページ・レイアウトも含めた仕様策定が進んでおり、その上で XSL-FO 組版と比較できるのかなと思っておりました。

Comment: しっかり調べておられるようですね．おっしゃられる通りです．また、現状はCSSを使った組版の方が勢いがありますね．感触としては、CSSの方がとっつき易く、ちょっとしたものを作るには向いているのですが、本格的にCSSで作り込んでいくのであれば、最初にしっかり設計しておかないとメンテナンスが大変になると思われます．

Answer (score 1):

XSL-FO と CSS のレイアウト制御を対比する一覧がありましたので共有します。（ベンダー組版ソフトウェアマニュアルの一部）

AH Formatter v65 Help XSL/CSSプロパティ一覧
http://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v65/ahf-focss6.html

一覧にはベンダー製品の機能機能も含められていますが、仕様で比較するならば機能拡張を加味しない形で比較できます。XSL、CSS の欄の片方に空欄となっている部分で、レイアウト制御の優位性が判断できるかと思います。

この情報は、XSL-FO組版とCSS組版でどちらを選択するか、組版の要求に沿った優位性を比較する判断材料として使用できそうです。
※優位性の要点を記載できればよいのですが、数が多くまとめきれていません・・